# Javascript function not working for radiobutton list

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function wherein based on selection I have to enable a row and disable a button on the same page. Earlier it was handled via code behind and was working fine with the same logic. Now it does not work.

**JS function:**

```
function ValidateRadioButtonList()
{         
   var RBL = document.getElementById('<%=rbListExamShot.ClientID%>');
   var radiobuttonlist = RBL.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var counter = 0;
   var atLeast = 1
   for (var i = 0; i < radiobuttonlist.length; i++) {
   if (radiobuttonlist[i].checked) {

   counter++;
   var selected = i;
   }
   }
   if (atLeast = counter) {
   // return arguments.IsValid;
   var RowMessage = document.getElementById  ('<%                               =RowCliamMessage.ClientID%>');
   RowMessage.style.display = "block";
   }
   else {

   RowMessage.style.display = "none";
   }
   if (selected == 1) {

   var Submit = document.getElementById('<%=Save.ClientID%>');
   Submit.disabled = true;
   return false;
   }
   else {
   return true;
   }
 }
```

asp.net control and validator:

```
   <td  align="left">
            <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="label" ID="rbListExamShot" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ValidationGroup="Save"  
                onselectedindexchanged="rbListExamShot_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Single Shot" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Double Shot" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </td>
            <td>
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Text="Please select voucher type"
                Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rbListExamShot" ValidationGroup="Save"
                ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="False"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save"
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage=".Double Shot Vouchers cannot be reimbursed."
                ControlToValidate="rbListExamShot" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateRadioButtonList"
                ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="False"></asp:CustomValidator>
        </td>
```

Comment: if (atLeast = counter)  check this condition, it should be '==' like if (atLeast == counter). may be it helps...

Comment: Thnaks for noting that..but the scenario that I am seeing right now..it works fine there..I need it to go within if condition and here it will in any case....the prolem is no error is being displayed and row is not gettign visible which i am trying to do.

Comment: what is 'RowCliamMessage' ? can you alert the variable RowMessage?? check is it undefined?

Comment: @Richa try placing `alert('checkpoint1');` inside `if (radiobuttonlist[i].checked) {}` block and then inside `if (atLeast = counter) {}` block one line after the other you might get the exact line of code where the pandora's box is unleashed

Comment: and as @Talha mentioned change the line `if (atLeast = counter)` to `if (atLeast == counter)` note that only positive values are treated as true in case of `if` block <br> and make sure there is no space/Tab character in the line `var RowMessage = document.getElementById  ('<%                               =RowCliamMessage.ClientID%>');` a lot of spaces found in-between **<%** and **=**

Comment: thanks everyone for their comments..the problem was that I was getting the client Id in var and then trying to set properties..now I am doing something like: document.getElementById('<%=Save.ClientID%>').disabled = true..and it is working for me!thanks all

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone for their comments..the problem was that I was getting the client Id in var and then trying to set properties..now I am doing something like: document.getElementById('<%=Save.ClientID%>').disabled = true..and it is working for me!thanks all

Answer (score -1):

```
<td  align="left">
        <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="label" ID="rbListExamShot" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ValidationGroup="Save"  
            onselectedindexchanged="rbListExamShot_SelectedIndexChanged();">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Single Shot" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Double Shot" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" Text="Please select voucher type"
            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rbListExamShot" ValidationGroup="Save"
            ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="False"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save"
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage=".Double Shot Vouchers cannot be reimbursed."
            ControlToValidate="rbListExamShot" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateRadioButtonList"
            ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="False"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </td>
```